# What is the implication of not being able to balance the complete combustion reaction equation of methanol?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

This question has been intriguing me since 10th or 11th grade. The teacher just told us about it but didn't get into the details of the why. Recently I asked a biochemist but couldn't get an answer. So I bring it here.

$$\ce{CH3OH + O2 -> CO2 + H2O}$$

is the complete combustion equation of methanol. But the problem is it can't be balanced. What is the practical implication, and significance of this fact?

*Side question:*

What is the mathematical reasoning behind the inability to balance the equation?

Comment: Wait, what do you mean it cannot be balanced?

Comment: Maybe it was some other equation. Just can't recall it, I'll update the question.

Comment: Please do. I'm very curious now.

Comment: I'm pretty sure every single valid chemical equation balances, as long of course as you know all the products. You could conceivably use a reaction as an analog computer (a very cumbersome one!) to solve a linear system of equations. If nature does it, then math must do it.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto Back then not being able to balance that equation was bugbear. Now not being able to recall is one. Argh.

Comment: This question has awoken the fire of linear algebra in me! I believe it is possible to prove that any system of equations resulting from a valid reaction has $n$ variables and $n-1$ equations, i.e. the system is always underdetermined by one equation and therefore has infinite solutions, all of which lie in a line in $\mathbb{R}^n$ sand are multiples of eachother by some arbitrary real number. Let me try formalizing the argument. Unfortunately I'm kind of tired, so I can't guarantee I'll be able to wade through the notation properly.

Comment: After playing with the question in my mind, it turns out to be quite interesting. I cannot prove that all valid chemical equations can be balanced, because it's actually the opposite cause and effect; *all equations that can be balanced are valid chemical equations*. Unfortunately I cannot provide as formal a proof as I thought, but I may write something up later.

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto You are quite right but I'm a TA for a gen. chem course and nobody seems to get that! "But sir, why are the coefficients 2,3,2,4 instead of 4,6,4,8?"

Comment: @CHM I haven't had the opportunity to teach class yet, but I would retort with something like "They can be. They can also be 20-30-20-40, and they can also be 634-951-634-1268, and even $\frac{1}{12}$-$\frac{1}{8}$-$\frac{1}{12}$-$\frac{1}{6}$. But it turns out that using the smallest numbers possible while avoiding fractions makes calculations simpler! Do you *want* to work more for no reason?"

Answer (score 3):

Here is the balanced eqn...

$$\ce{2 CH3OH + 3 O2 → 2 CO2 + 4 H2O}$$

Comment: While i was typing the the mathjaxed equation, you were faster submitting. So I beautify yours :-D

Comment: @KlausWarzecha Can you beautify me next??

Comment: @LordStryker I might be good, but not THAT good :-P

Comment: beatify or beautify?

Comment: @ron Blessed are the cheesemakers.

Answer (score 0):

Mass is conserved, charge is conserved, ignore spectator ions until the end.  If it is a redox reaction, begin by listing each active atom's reduction or oxidation, e.g.,

Mn(+7) + 5e to Mn(+2)

Cr(+3) - 3e to Cr(+6)

and find the least common denominator (here, 15).  That gives you the primary stoichiometry, here 5Cr(+3) (going to chromate) with 3Mn(+7) (coming from permanganate).  Add the other atoms, slop in H2O, OH-, or H+, add back the spectator ions. Confirm the same number of each kind of atom on both sides.  Try it out,

CuSCN + KIO3 + HCl to CuSO4 + KCl + HCN + ICl + H2O

[Cr(N2H4CO)6]4[Cr(CN)6]3 + KMnO4 + H2SO4 to K2Cr2O7 + MnSO4 +CO2 + KNO3 + K2SO4+ H2O